# Analytical flow-chart - decide what number must be in a specified box

Tags: flowchart

I am having a lot of trouble in solving the following flowchart question.
Could you please help me as soon as possible as i have interview tomorrow?

4th question in the following link

http://placement.freshersworld.com/placement-papers/ThoughtWorks/Placement-Paper-Whole-Testpaper-18522

I cant the question as it has some structures that wont display properly here. 
Please go to the link.

Thanks,
Arjun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would be "3", since you want to stop the flow when the number in box 3 is the same as the number in box 8.

**EDIT**

If we skip to the last iteration of the loop, the steps are

1. Subtract: 9 - 9. Put result into box 6
2. Change Instruction 1. Increase box 6 by 2 (To box 8)
3. Is Box 8 (because we changed it in step 2) equal to box 3?

if box 8 and box 3 are the same, you end the flow.

Comment: Thank you very much Cavyn. But may be I am dumb:(.. i am not able to understand why it is so? why should it be same as the number in box 8..  thx once again for the prompt reply..

Comment: in the first setp.. should we not put the result into Box 2?

Comment: Step 1 changes every loop iteration because of step 2. So in the first iteration, you change box 2, in the second iteration you change box 4, then box 6, then (as seen in my example), box 8.

Comment: but we dont know the value in Box 3. so how does step 3 work?

Comment: The whole point of the exorcise to to walk through the steps mentally to figure out what should be in box 3. After the first iteration, the loop still needs to continue, so you know the number in box 3 cannot equal the number in box 4. After the second you know it can't equal the number in box 6. After the third iteration, the conditions have been satisfied (boxes 2, 4, and 6 all have 0s), so you can set box 3 to be the same as box 8.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I understood it now... Can you look at problem 5 aswell... if you cant reply here.. Please send an email to mallunc@gmail.com

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted to let others know the question is closed.

Comment: Done :) marked as answer.. :)

Comment: Dear Cavyn, can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981770/analytical-flow-chart-add-up-the-numbers-in-boxes-6-7-8-and-9-and-put-the-t

Comment: It's a very similar thought process to this question. Keep in mind that this site isn't designed to help with specific questions like this, but rather generic questions that multiple people could encounter. I recommend writing out the steps one by one on paper, and see where you end up.